# Getting -[SearchViewController tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, uisearchbar

The following is the code for a View Controller in which I'm adding a Search bar and performing things:

SearchViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SearchViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISearchBar *search;

@end
```

SearchViewController.m

```
#import "SearchViewController.h"
#import "MMDrawerController/UIViewController+MMDrawerController.h"

@interface SearchViewController ()

@end

@implementation SearchViewController

@synthesize search;

- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden
{
    return YES;
}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self)
    {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [search.delegate self];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(dismissKeyboard)];

    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tap];
    [search setShowsCancelButton:YES animated:NO];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - UITextFieldMethod

-(void) textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [search resignFirstResponder];
}

-(BOOL) textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [search resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}

#pragma mark - HandlingKeyboard

-(void) dismissKeyboard
{
    [search resignFirstResponder];
}

#pragma mark - UISearchBarMethods

- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    [search resignFirstResponder];
    [search endEditing:YES];
    [self.mm_drawerController toggleDrawerSide:MMDrawerSideRight animated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void) searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    [search resignFirstResponder];
    [self.mm_drawerController toggleDrawerSide:MMDrawerSideRight animated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)searchBarTextDidEndEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    [search resignFirstResponder];
}

@end
```

While clicking in the search bar to enter text, I'm getting an error of:

> -[SearchViewController tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8e68990

Comment: Might be unrelated, but what do you mean by `[search.delegate self];`? I'm surprised you didn't get at least a warning. Did you mean `search.delegate = self`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From error it looks like that your app try too find table view delegate methods.  Couple of check

1. Can you remove code for
   "MMDrawerController/UIViewController+MMDrawerController.h" and try?
2. Does your nib file contain table view? If yes can you check if its
   connected to any IBOutlets or not?

Comment: Why is this the answer?  Why is the search bar looking for table view methods?  The VC does not say it is a table view controller, and that is not a required method of a search bar delegate.